How to move a Mathematica plot between two notebooks?
I have a long complicated notebook that performs some simulations of a physical system and generates a series of 3D plots. From that original notebook I made a few new ones for modifications to the physical system.
Now I want to overplot (with "Show[]") some plots from separate notebooks. The problem is that I did not re-name variables and functions when creating new notebooks, so in order to run two of these notebooks (and get the plots from each) I need to clear the kernel in-between.
I tried exporting the plot from one notebook to another - but it does this only at the level of the graphics and then trying to use Show[] with multiple elements just breaks.
Is there a quick/easy solution? Thanks and all the best!

Did you try Save[] / Get[]  ? You can save and restore various data : not only graphics but also variables and functions.

Also Export[] then Import[] as a .m file works most of the time.

Do you know that you can copy/paste graphics between notebooks?
If you have too many graphics in the source notebook to do it by hand, you can assemble them in one plot using Show and transfer this new plot.
A further possibility is to give the graphics in the source windows new names that do not conflict with the target window.

@A.Kato this worked. Thanks!
